# Drupal paid subscription manager where nodes are removed upon expiration

Tags: 7, ubercart, commerce, notifications

I would like to charge my users to post content. For example, 1$ per node/ week that it's visible.

Now I know there are many subscription modules. But how can I manage a subscription system with re-occurring payments, which also automatically interacts with my website and makes changes in real time. For example - how can I have nodes 'expire' after 2 weeks if the user only pays for two weeks.

Are there any combination of modules people would recommend to use to implement such a system?
I was thinking of [Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart), [UC Node Checkout](http://drupal.org/project/uc_node_checkout), [Node Published](http://drupal.org/project/uc_node_published), however these are D6 modules and i've been on D7 for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You want [Commerce License](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_license), a framework built exactly for that. You can write a custom license type that creates / deletes the node when the license status changes (and it would be a good candidate for a generic contrib).

The recurring side is handled by [Commerce License Billing](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_license_billing).

EDIT: There is now a [Commerce License Node](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_license_node) project too, doing what I described.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this out http://nicksantamaria.net/article/commerce-subscriptions? Using this module you can purchase role and the expiry of the role is set by rule schedular